# WPF attach code behind handler for every mouse up/move event

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, events

I have my view build up with a `TreeListView` and its content is generated by a datatemplate.
I now need to handle all the mousemove/mouseup events in my view on whatever visual element they may be attached to.

Is there a way to set an eventhandler so it will catch all my event, regardsless if my mouseup is on a specific tree item, on the tree, or even on my main view?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Most routed event has a Preview event in WPF, You can handle `PreviewMouseUp` and `PreviewMoueDown` event on your `View`.

Comment: This is not working, when i click inside the treeview and i have a mouseup, the preview event from the view is not being triggered

Comment: the TreeListView inherits from a treeview and the items inherits from the treeviewitem. But not of these subclasses override or give a different implementation of the mouse events

Comment: Is there anything that would potentially capture the mouse in your `DataTemplate`? In normal cases this works and I was able to handle the events as mentioned in a test project.

Comment: i want to change my cursor for drag&drop so when i have an item selected its not using the default icons but i generated a cursor with my item, this being displayed with each mousemove event